A Workouts in Intermediate microeconomics (Hal Varian) equivalent but for Macro
As the question implies, I'm studying for entrance exams, and I found workouts in intermediate microeconomics insanely helpful, just a bunch of questions of all kinds. I was wondering of there was an alternative in macro for the same.
